# Checkbox not binding to controller

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I used Ajax to retrieve information from the controller and display it as a list of checkboxes in my view.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submitButton').hide(); //hide some buttons
    $("#Name").hide();
    $("#Contact").hide();
    $("#Desc").hide();
    $("#PMeeting").hide();
    $("#Params").hide();

    $('#SelectedTeam').change(function () {
        $('#content').html('');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Audits/GetAuditParams', //this function retrieves a list of objects
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                'tn': $('#SelectedTeam').val(),
            },
            success: function (data) { //here I create the table with checkboxes and labels
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    var li = $('<input type="checkbox" value="' + item.Included + '" name=Parameters[' + i + '].Included id=Parameters_' + i + '__Included"/>' +
          '<label for="Parameters[' + i + ']"></label></br>').
                        text(item.ParameterDescription).prop('checked', item.Included);

                    li.find('label').text(item.ParameterDescription);//I create a set of hiddem fields with the same new, otherwise the collection will be null in the controller

                    $('<input>').attr({
                        type: 'hidden',
                        id: 'Parameters_' + i + '__Included',
                        name: 'Parameters[' + i + '].Included'
                    }).appendTo('form');
                    $('#content').append(li);
                });
            }
        });
        $.ajax({ //this is for a different information
            url: '/Audits/GetAuditInfo',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                'tn': $('#SelectedTeam').val(),
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#SProject_ProjectName").val(data.ProjectID);
                $("#SProject_POC").val(data.POC);
                $("#SProject_PDescription").val(data.PDescription);
                $("#SProject_PeriodicMeeting").val(data.PeriodicMeeting);
                $("#Name").show();
                $("#Contact").show();
                $("#Desc").show();
                $("#PMeeting").show();
                $("#Params").show();

            }
        });
        $('#submitButton').show();

    });

    function isChecked(value) {

        if (value == 1) {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', function (index, value) {
            if (value == true) {
                $('#Parameters_' + index + '__Included').val(1);
                $('#Parameters_' + index + '__Included').prop('checked', "checked");
            } else {
                $('#Parameters_' + index + '__Included').val(0);
            }

        });
    });
});
```

This is my HTML code

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="col-md-4" id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But I'm getting the information for the checkboxes null in the controller, `ModelStated.isvalid = false` and this is the error

> The value '0' is not valid for Included.

and also all the checkboxes (checked or unchecked) have the value of "false".

Answer (score 2):

You should provide a little more information and rephrase your statements in the form of a specific question. Other than that, I don't think that is all your code, that looks like a blank HTML page. If you would like to get data from an MVC controller, you should create a model which your controller will provide to your view. Here is an example of how you can do that:

[Accessing your model's data from a controller - asp.net](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller)

Essentially, you create a model and a database context, then create an instance of the context in your controller.

```
public class YourController : Controller
{
    private YourDBContext db = new YourDBContext();
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.YourData.ToList());
    }

}
```

Pass that from your controller to your view using razor syntax.

```
@model IEnumerable<App.Model.Data>
```

Use razor to bind the checkboxes to your model

```
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.data)
```

In general, I find it easier to use more razor with html/bootstrap and less jQuery. It is hard to solve your checkbox problem without seeing your model or controller, but if you focus on the basics of MVC I think a lot of your issues will be sorted out. I'm sorry that this answer is not very specific, but if you revise your question I can be more specific.